# How to perform this Buffer Overflow? in Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, buffer, overflow

```
#include <stdio.h>

int myprint(char* argv1) {
    printf("%s", argv1); 
}

void foo(char* argv1, char* argv2) {
int (*fptr)(char*) = myprint; 
char buf[12];
strcpy(buf, argv1); 
fptr(argv2); }

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
if (argc < 3) 
{ 
printf("error\n"); 
return; 
} 
foo(argv[1], argv[2]); }
```

This is the c code I want to overflow. I already disable the aslr. What do I do next?

Answer (score 1):

=======1=======

In your function `foo`, the next code will cause a buffer overflow

```
strcpy(buf, argv1);
```

because the length of the `buf` is only 12(`char buf[12]`)

`strcpy` will copy the value from the source address `arg1` to `buf` until it encounters a '\0' in `arg1`.

So if you give an `arg1` whose length is larger than 12, you will get a buffer overflow.

=======2=======

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

The parameter `int argc` is the number of command line parameters and the next parameter `char **argv` is a pointer which points to those parameters, argv[0] being the name of your program.
So, compile your code like this( say the source file is `test.c` ):

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

and then run it like this:

```
./test this_is_argv1_its_length_larget_han_12 this_is_argv2
```